# how to create and export dynamic operators

Tags: raku

I have some classes (and will need quite a few more) that look like this:

```
use Unit;

class Unit::Units::Ampere is Unit
{
  method TWEAK { with self {
    .si            = True;
                   #     m·  kg·   s·   A   ·K· mol·  cd
    .si-signature  = [   0,   0,   0,   1,   0,   0,   0 ];
    .singular-name = "ampere";
    .plural-name   = "ampere";
    .symbol        = "A";
  }}

  sub postfix:<A> ($value) returns Unit::Units::Ampere is looser(&prefix:<->) is export(:short) {
    return Unit::Units::Ampere.new( :$value );
  };

  sub postfix:<ampere> ($value) returns Unit::Units::Ampere is looser(&prefix:<->) is export(:long) {
    $value\A;
  };
}
```

I would like to be able to construct and export the custom operators dynamically at runtime. I know how to work with EXPORT, but how do I create a postfix operator on the fly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up basically doing [this](https://github.com/holli-holzer/perl6-Units/blob/a5223754739a1647152b2372509b615e927844a8/lib/Units.pm6):

```
sub EXPORT
{
    return %(
        "postfix:<A>" => sub is looser(&prefix:<->) {
            #do something
          }
    );
}
```

which is disturbingly simple.

Comment: Do you mind if I add a version of this to the EXPORT documentation? It's a neat trick, and I know what you mean by "disturbingly simple".

Comment: No, why would I?

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, you can create dynamic subs by returning a sub from another. To accept only an `Ampere` parameter (where "Ampere" is chosen programmatically), use a [type capture](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Signature.html#Type_Captures) in the function signature:

```
sub make-combiner(Any:U ::Type $, &combine-logic) {
    return sub (Type $a, Type $b) {
        return combine-logic($a, $b);
    }
}

my &int-adder = make-combiner Int, {$^a + $^b};
say int-adder(1, 2);
my &list-adder = make-combiner List, {(|$^a, |$^b)};
say list-adder(<a b>, <c d>);
say list-adder(1, <c d>); # Constraint type check fails
```

Note that when I defined the inner `sub`, I had to put a space after the `sub` keyword, lest the compiler think I'm calling a function named "sub". (See the end of my answer for another way to do this.)

Now, on to the hard part: how to export one of these generated functions? The documentation for what `is export` really does is here: https://docs.perl6.org/language/modules.html#is_export

Half way down the page, they have an example of adding a function to the symbol table without being able to write `is export` at compile time. To get the above working, it needs to be in a separate file. To see an example of a programmatically determined name and programmatically determined logic, create the following MyModule.pm6:

```
unit module MyModule;

sub make-combiner(Any:U ::Type $, &combine-logic) {
    anon sub combiner(Type $a, Type $b) {
        return combine-logic($a, $b);
    }
}

my Str $name = 'int';
my $type = Int;
my package EXPORT::DEFAULT {
    OUR::{"&{$name}-eater"} := make-combiner $type, {$^a + $^b};
}
```

Invoke Perl 6:

```
perl6 -I. -MMyModule -e "say int-eater(4, 3);"
```

As hoped, the output is 7. Note that in this version, I used `anon sub`, which lets you name the "anonymous" generated function. I understand this is mainly useful for generating better stack traces.

All that said, I'm having trouble dynamically setting a postfix operator's precedence. I think you need to modify the `Precedence` role of the operator, or create it yourself instead of letting the compiler create it for you. This isn't documented.

Comment: You don't need to call `&` sigiled functions with the `&`. `sub foo ( &bar, $arg ){ say bar $arg }`. In fact `sub foo ($a){ say $a }` is mostly the same as `my &foo = -> $a { say $a }`

Comment: `sub make-combiner ( Any:U ::Type $, &combine-logic ){ anon sub combiner ( Type $a, Type $b ) { combine-logic $a, $b }}`

Comment: @BradGilbert Thanks, I cleaned that up in the examples.

Comment: You needed to remove the `.` as that does require using `&`

Comment: @BradGilbert Thanks for all the tips! I've incorporated them. `::Type` type capture is especially cool!